# Follow up to Pinter's abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, advice

I wanted to learn abstract algebra this summer so I bought Pinter's *A book of Abstract Algebra*.

I was planning on reading it over the course of the summer, but just finished the last problem of its final chapter! I found the subject absolutely enthralling and now want to learn more, as such my question is:

**What algebra textbooks/topics would provide a good follow up to Pinter's text?**

Edit: Please note that my prerequsites are somewhat limited. As far as serious math classes, I've only taken ODEs, probability, and Analysis 1 (Rudin Ch 1-6).

Comment: Herstein, Topics in Algebra is a classic, but may be quite advanced. Also, check out book by Gallian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these classics:

- *Algebra* by Mac Lane and Birkoff.
  This will introduce you to categorical ideas in a painless way by the masters.
- *Basic Algebra I* and *II* by Jacobson, now available in a [Dover edition](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486471896.html).
  I like the prose in these books, written by a master expositor. Volume II is hard.

Comment: What is the difference between *Algebra* by Mac Lane and Birkoff and *A Survey of Modern Algebra* by the same authors? Which one is more advanced?

Comment: @Graduate, *Algebra* is more advanced.