# Examples of finite commutative rings that are not fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Would someone be able to provide examples of finite commutative rings that are not fields? I attempted to create commutative rings using matrices (ie permutation matrices) and integers (ie $\mathbb{Z}_p$), however, either they were not rings or they were fields.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7133/classification-of-finite-commutative-rings

Comment: [Here is the DaRT search result set](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=43&L=54) . At present, it's just several quotients of $\mathbb Z$ and then a finite quotient of $F_2[x,y]$.

Comment: $\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z$, $p$ prime, $k>1$.

Comment: And of course, any number of combinations of finite products of rings of the types anyone mentions will be another example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_4$, why not?  Beginning students may think that the field of $4$ element is this, but it is not, so this is a good example to talk about.

A finite commutative ring with no zero divisors is a field, so we have to look for zero divisors to get an example that you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

Take $A \times B$, where $A$ and $B$ are finite commutative rings, even fields.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough classification. Any finite commutative ring is in particular [Artinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring), and commutative Artinian rings $R$ are finite products $\prod_m R_m$ of Artinian [local rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring); more specifically they have [finitely many maximal ideals $m$ and are the products of the localizations at each maximal ideal](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J4).

So we can reduce to the local case. If $R$ is a finite commutative local ring with maximal ideal $m$ then the quotient $R/m$ is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, and $m$ is nilpotent. So, roughly speaking, finite commutative local rings look like finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ with some extra "nilpotent fuzz" attached. The two easiest classes of examples to describe here are $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/t^k$, both of which are $\mathbb{F}_p$ with some extra "nilpotent fuzz" attached. One can contemplate more complicated quotients of this sort, e.g. $\mathcal{O}_K/P^k$ where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of a number field and $P$ is a prime ideal in it, which is $\mathcal{O}_K/P$ with some extra "nilpotent fuzz" attached.

Among other things, it follows that the smallest examples of finite commutative rings that are not fields have order $4$, and include $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[t]/t^2$, as well as the simpler $\mathbb{F}_2^2$. I believe these are the only examples of order $4$.

Comment: I think nilpotent fuzz can be treated effectively with minoxidil.

Comment: Unclear why you think that describing $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ as $\Bbb{F}_2$ with some nilpotent fuzz is correct.

Comment: @reuns: what do you mean? It's a local ring with a unique maximal ideal $m$, namely $(2)$, the quotient by that maximal ideal is $\mathbb{F}_2$, and $m$ is nilpotent. The "roughly speaking" was very deliberate, of course I don't literally mean that some nilpotents have just been adjoined.

Answer (score 1):

What about the $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Would that be a commutative ring? Multiplication is not commutative on matrices.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a nonempty finite set and $R$ be a finite ring. Take the set $R^X$ of all mappings $f:X\rightarrow R$. This set becomes a ring with $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $f,g\in R^X$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any finite field $F$ and a finite dimentional $F$-vector space $V$; then the set
$F\times V$ with addition
$$
(a,x)+(b,y)=(a+b,x+y)
$$
and multiplication
$$
(a,x)(b,y)=(ab,ay+bx)
$$
is easily seen to be a commutative finite ring. Taking as $F$ the field with $2048$ elements and $\dim V=1003$, I guess this is far enough from examples of type $\mathbb{Z}_m$ or variants thereof.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a commutative ring with unity for all *n*.  [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1934216/1140344).  But it is a *field* if and only if *n* is prime.  See [this different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/522921/1140344).  Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for *n* composite is a commutative ring with unity but is not a field.  The simplest example is $\mathbb{Z}_4$, as per GEdgar.

My abstract algebra book, [Pinter](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832697/1140344) page 172, says "If *A* is a *commutative ring with unity* in which every nonzero element is invertible, A is called a *field*." In $\mathbb{Z}_4$, 2 is not invertible.